# The width of the tube in manometer

Tags: pressure

[image]

In manometer, the height(h) in the figure is dependent on the pressure of gas supply and the density of the liquid in the tube.
why the height (h) in manometer is **independent** on the width of the tube?

For example, when I think if I use narrower tube, the height (h) increases.
why this is wrong?

Comment: Are you asking about the possible effect of surface tension (which would be the same on both sides) or the diameters of the tubes on either side being different?

Comment: diameter of the tubes of the tube (U-shape)

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason why $P=h\rho g$. Here, $\rho h$ can be written as $\frac{h\rho A}{A}$ ($A$ is the area of cross section of the tube), where $\rho hA =m$ (mass).

The fact is that the pressure is independent of the area of cross section, and hence the width of the tube.

Summarising the above,

Weight is dependent on the density and volume of the water (and volume = area times the depth). Moreover, pressure is force per area. The pressure basically then depends only on the *depth*. The same logic applies here. The area of cross sections have no role in here.

Comment: Actually I did not understand the idea behind all these equations, can you please figure it out with more simple method.

Comment: This is a simple method. All you have to see is that area of cross section does not play a role here at all. Go through the derivation for $P=h\rho g$. In that you see exactly why area cancels out. What I wrote here was to show that idea.

Comment: If the area cancels out in the derivation, so why we use it in the equation "pressure = force /area" , the pressure is inversely proportional with area, but in the another equation "P= density*h*g" so that area doesn't affect the pressure,Can you please clarify this for me

Comment: Because force here which is the weight depends on area. So it cancels out. In a general context, force would not have been a function of the area. It depends on the type of problem.

Comment: An example is the force due to gravity inside of the earth varies differently with depth compared to the distance from the earth outside of it. Both are gravity, but the relation of $F$ with respect to $r$ is different - in one case it is $1/r^2$ and in the other case it would be $(1-d/R)$.

Answer (score 0):

The pressures must balance on the two sides, left and right.

$$ p_L = p_o + \rho g \Delta h = p_R$$

Expand the pressures as forces per area. Expand density as mass per volume.

$$ \frac{f_o}{A_L} + \frac{m_L}{A_L \Delta h} g \Delta h = p_R $$

The final expression gives this with tube radius $R_L$.

$$ {f_o} + m_L g  = p_R A_L = p_R (2\pi R_L^2)$$

Tube width affects the force we can exert on the left, not pressure. This is the principle behind a [hydraulic jack](https://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae526.cfm).

Comment: So according to the last equation, as the radius increases, the force increases so the height in the figure wil be higher!!!